# Entity framework code first map stored procedures with composite primary keys

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I want to use EF code first to connect my model classes to my database, for example:

```
public partial class Header
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int DeviceId { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

and in my DbContext

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Header>().HasKey(k => new { k.Id, k.DeviceId });
    modelBuilder.Entity<Header>().MapToStoredProcedures(s =>
    {
        s.Update(u => u.HasName("dbo.SpUpdateHeader"));
        s.Insert(i =>
            i.HasName("dbo.SpInsertHeader")
            .Result<int>(r => r.Id, "Id"));
        s.Delete(d => d.HasName("dbo.SpDeleteHeader"));
     });
}
```

The DeviceId is fixed to the device that the record is generated, and the Id is the identity generated on that device.
This DbContext is used to sync all the devices data on the server.

The problem with this code is that on insert, i get this error:
A result binding for the property 'Id' was not found on the modification function 'SpInsertHeader'. Ensure that the property is database generated.

And if i set [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)] attribute or         [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)] that property is never sent to the stored procedure

What can i do to enable this scenario?

EDIT

```
PROCEDURE [dbo].[SpInsertHeader] 
  @Id INT,
  @DeviceId INT
AS
BEGIN
--get new id
IF(COALESCE(@Id, 0) = 0)
BEGIN
    SELECT TOP 1 @Id = COALESCE(h.Id, 0) + 1
    FROM Header h
    WHERE h.DeviceId = @DeviceId
    ORDER BY h.Id DESC;
END

IF(COALESCE(@Id, 0) = 0)
BEGIN
    SET @Id = 1;
END

INSERT INTO Header(Id, DeviceId) VALUES (@Id, @DeviceId);

SELECT @Id AS 'Id';
END
```

Comment: `SpInsertHeader` should return the generated identity value named as `Id`.

Comment: See my edit, i forgot the actual SP

Comment: OK, so `Id` is not db-generated (you already said so, in retrospect...). I assume it's properly mapped as primary key? I think you shouldn't return anything from the sproc (but I'm not doing this very often).

Comment: But if i don't return anything i never get the Id if the record is generated on the server, and not on a device.

Comment: You can't mix db-generated and explicitly setting the key value. In this case, if you need the generated key value, you have to reread it manually after `SaveChanges`.

Comment: How can i get the id after the SaveChanges?
I'm trying to see if this  [blog post](https://colinmackay.scot/2012/12/30/getting-entity-framework-to-pick-up-on-the-auto-generated-part-of-the-composite-primary-key/) can help me on this one

Answer (score 0):

After much testing and googling, i found [this blog post](https://colinmackay.scot/2012/12/30/getting-entity-framework-to-pick-up-on-the-auto-generated-part-of-the-composite-primary-key/) with help me found a solution to my problem.
I realize that i cannot get the database generated id, on the server created objects, and app generated id, for the diferent devices with the same DbContext.

So i need a way to have to 2 diferent model mappings, so i created a UseApiModel property on my DbContext and on the OnModelCreating method i set

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Header>().Property(t => t.Id)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
```

and

```
s.Insert(i => i.HasName("dbo.SpInsertHeader").Result<int>(r => r.Id, "Id"));
```

or

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Header>().Property(t => t.Id)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);
```

and

```
s.Insert(i => i.HasName("dbo.SpApiInsertHeader"));
```

Depending on the UseApiModel property.

The Api SP expect a valid Id key and the other SP will generate one, i need two SP's because EF will send the Id property or not depending on the DatabaseGeneratedOption.

I also use the Colin Angus Mackay advise to generate the Id on a INSTEAD OF INSERT